# list index out of range error (second time)

Tags: python, selenium

This code works for the first line of the input file but fails in the second trial  and I don't know why. I tried to see if there are similar questions but I didn't found a solution.

```
carac=":"
fichier = open("test", "r")
for i in range(2):
    time.sleep(0.5)

    chaine = fichier.readline().split(carac)
    print(chaine[0])

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\bh\Downloads\chromedriver')
    driver.get('https://www.twitter.com/login')
    username_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name('js-username-field')
    username_box.send_keys(chaine[0])
    password_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name('js-password-field')
    password_box.send_keys(chaine[1])
```

I have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/bh/PycharmProjects/test/twitter.py", line 199, in <module>
    password_box.send_keys(chaine[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

ps: the document is a .txt
in the document there is something like this :

```
test@gmail.com:pass
test@gmail.com:pass
```

Comment: What's your input file?

Comment: I down-voted your question, because it is unspecific, does not comply with the title-requirements and seems to have only very limited relevance for the community

Comment: it's a '.txt' document

Comment: Your `.txt` document seems to have two lines. What is in this document?

Comment: in the document there a something like   :              test@gmaiil.com:pass                                          test@gmaiil.com:pass

Comment: What's in it? You're splitting on a colon. If there's no column any reference to chaine elements other than 0 will throw this exception.

Comment: there is a colon in each line

Comment: My guess would be that there is a newline at the end of the file. You can confirm this by checking what the last chaine[0] is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this happens because you havent assigned a value to chaine[1].
You need to declare it before you use it. Why you use a sleep function? 
print chaine[1] to see if its empty or not

Comment: ok i did , now it tell me : password = chaine[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: i use the sleep because sometimes the page take time to charge

Comment: carac=":"                                                                                                          
     fichier = open("test.txt", "r")
     chaine = [0] * 2   #declare chaine and fill it with zeros
     for i in range(2):
          chaine[i]= fichier.readline().split(carac)
          print(chaine[i][0]) #so no chaine[0][0] -> the first email